# SSL Policy Errors

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

Please forgive me if this is more of a security question. I am confused when I see example code such as the following:

```
public bool customCertificateValidation(Object sender, 
       X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, 
       SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) 
{
      {
       case RemoteCertificateChainErrors:
            // some check, returning true or false 
       case RemoteCertificateNameMismatch:
            // some check...
       case RemoteCertificateNotAvailable:
            // some check...                   
  }
```

sslPolicyErrors is supposed to be a bitmap. If it has multiple bits set it won't match a case, and if it only gets sent one error, the check on the other one won't happen. It is conceivable you could have both RemoteCertificateChainErrors and RemoteCertificateNameMismatch. So this is wrong?

However if it is a server validating a client, I believe you can't get RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, and it could only logically be one of the other two? (but not both).

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment.

Disclaimer: this is *only* based on how I grok the documentation for [`SslPolicyErrors Enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslpolicyerrors?view=net-5.0)

- This seems directly relevant to your question (emphasis mine):

  > This enumeration has a [`FlagsAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute) attribute that **allows a bitwise combination of its member values**.

The examples for [FlagsAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute) clarifies it even more.

Example directly taken from that page:

```
using System;

class Example
{
   // Define an Enum without FlagsAttribute.
   enum SingleHue : short
   {
      None = 0,
      Black = 1,
      Red = 2,
      Green = 4,
      Blue = 8
   };

   // Define an Enum with FlagsAttribute.
   [Flags]
   enum MultiHue : short
   {
      None = 0,
      Black = 1,
      Red = 2,
      Green = 4,
      Blue = 8
   };

   static void Main( )
   {
      // Display all possible combinations of values.
      Console.WriteLine(
           "All possible combinations of values without FlagsAttribute:");
      for(int val = 0; val <= 16; val++ )
         Console.WriteLine( "{0,3} - {1:G}", val, (SingleHue)val);

      // Display all combinations of values, and invalid values.
      Console.WriteLine(
           "\nAll possible combinations of values with FlagsAttribute:");
      for( int val = 0; val <= 16; val++ )
         Console.WriteLine( "{0,3} - {1:G}", val, (MultiHue)val);
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       All possible combinations of values without FlagsAttribute:
//         0 - None
//         1 - Black
//         2 - Red
//         3 - 3
//         4 - Green
//         5 - 5
//         6 - 6
//         7 - 7
//         8 - Blue
//         9 - 9
//        10 - 10
//        11 - 11
//        12 - 12
//        13 - 13
//        14 - 14
//        15 - 15
//        16 - 16
//
//       All possible combinations of values with FlagsAttribute:
//         0 - None
//         1 - Black
//         2 - Red
//         3 - Black, Red
//         4 - Green
//         5 - Black, Green
//         6 - Red, Green
//         7 - Black, Red, Green
//         8 - Blue
//         9 - Black, Blue
//        10 - Red, Blue
//        11 - Black, Red, Blue
//        12 - Green, Blue
//        13 - Black, Green, Blue
//        14 - Red, Green, Blue
//        15 - Black, Red, Green, Blue
//        16 - 16
```

> The preceding example defines two color-related enumerations,
> `SingleHue` and `MultiHue`. The latter has the `FlagsAttribute` attribute;
> the former does not. The example shows the difference in behavior when
> a range of integers, including integers that do not represent
> underlying values of the enumeration type, are cast to the enumeration
> type and their string representations displayed. For example, note
> that 3 cannot be represented as a `SingleHue` value because 3 is not the
> underlying value of any `SingleHue` member, whereas the `FlagsAttribute`
> attribute makes it possible to represent 3 as a `MultiHue` value of
> `Black`, `Red`.

Hth.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, which is why many examples I saw don't make sense on that basis. I wondered if in this specific context you were only presented with one of them.